# Load Images and description into overlay (HTML/CSS/PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, csv

I have a grid of thumbnails that when clicked on I want to load an overlay on the page showing the full size image and the contents of a text file as a caption.

Something like
`<a href="images/1001.jpg"><image src="thumbs/1001.jpg"></a>` would just load the image, but I want to load the image in a light box sort of view and also load the contents to "desc/1001.txt" into a caption (not necessarily a `<caption>`) below the image.

I don't want it to reload the page if that can be avoided. If it helps, the images, thumbnails, and description all match the pattern above, or I also have a CSV file in the format of `1000,"Description of the picture"` if that is simpler.

Comment: don't roll up your own if you can help it, it'll just take more time, use existing ones, like fancybox or the like

Comment: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: its the same idea, load up a small image used as thumbnail initially, the data src tag is taken as the large or original size and loaded when clicked

Comment: The trouble is not the lightbox so much, as adding the text to the lightbox image, That's where i am stuck.

Comment: https://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2013/11/01/responsive-css3-lightbox-with-no-javascript/ works for the lightbox in just HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started this should be fairly easy.

Your PHP code would look something like this:

```
<?php
$photos = [1000,1001];
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $description = file_get_contents('desc/' . $photo . '.jpg');
    echo '<a href="images/' . $photo . '" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="' . $description . '">' . $photo . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yep, I was just coming back with a “doh”…